# Select and group by - calculated field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some issues to complete a SQL statement in SQL Server 2008.

My 'query1' is the following:

```
SELECT [Vc_MONTH],
       [Vc_STATE],
       [Vc_PRODUCT],
       SUM ([TOTAL]) as Total_Units,
       SUM ([OPEN]) as Open_Units

FROM [test].[dbo].[Tbl_Summary]

GROUP BY [Vc_MONTH],
         [Vc_REGION],
         [Vc_PRODUCT],
```

This query selects Month, Region, Product, Sum of Total Units and Sum of Open Units.

I already group by Month, Region and Product. (I have plenty more lines)

This query works.

What I need is another 'query2' that groups by (ALL) the months listed on the table and then an union of this two selects.

At the end I need something like this

query1

```
|MONTH | STATE | PRODUCT | TOTAL | OPEN |
|:-----|:------|:--------|:------|:-----|
|JAN   | CA    | PENCIL  | 200   | 160 |
|JAN   | FL    | BOOK    | 300   | 280 |
|FEB   | CA    | PENCIL  | 180   | 150 |
|FEB   | FL    | PENCIL  | 250   | 100 |
|MAR   | CA    | BOOK    | 250   | 100 |
|MAR   | FL    | BOOK    | 100   | 50  |
```

query2 - This is what I need

```
|MONTH | STATE | PRODUCT | TOTAL | OPEN |
|:-----|:------|:--------|:------|:-----|
|JAN   | CA    | PENCIL  | 200   | 160 |
|JAN   | FL    | BOOK    | 300   | 280 |
|FEB   | CA    | PENCIL  | 180   | 150 |
|FEB   | FL    | PENCIL  | 250   | 100 |
|MAR   | CA    | BOOK    | 250   | 100 |
|MAR   | FL    | BOOK    | 100   | 50  |
```

UNION

```
|ALL   | CA    | PENCIL  | 380   | 310 |
|ALL   | CA    | BOOK    | 250   | 100 |
|ALL   | FL    | PENCIL  | 250   | 100 |
|ALL   | FL    | BOOK    | 400   | 330 |
```

Thanks in advance,
Luis

Comment: Sorry your question isnt clear. Why CA rows are join into `ALL` but FL doesnt? What two `select` will be join? Maybe a bigger sample data will help

Comment: what about `CA` and `FL` difference?

Comment: Sorry still not clear, now you include TX and NV in query1 but disapear on query2. I will refer you to this article [**Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

Comment: My bad! I was trying to give you a better example but my table wasn't quite right. Thanks for your time! The answer below works for now.

Comment: Good. Sometimes you can be lucky. But other times is a waste of time try to solve a question until the problem is clear. You may end solving a problem isnt the one OP want.

Comment: Please re-look at the answer by Gordon Linoff below that uses `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` - this is far more efficient than doing 2 queries and a UNION ALL (and **UNION ALL** is far more efficient than just UNION).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you already have query 1:

```
SELECT [Vc_MONTH],
   [Vc_STATE],
   [Vc_PRODUCT],
   SUM ([TOTAL]) as Total_Units,
   SUM ([OPEN]) as Open_Units
FROM [test].[dbo].[Tbl_Summary]
GROUP BY [Vc_MONTH],
     [Vc_STATE],
     [Vc_PRODUCT]
```

next you need to GROUP BY Month and Product correct? However, you need to specify a value in the 'Vc_STATE' column so that result sets from the two queries return the same columns.

```
UNION
SELECT [Vc_MONTH],
   'ALL STATES',
   [Vc_PRODUCT],
   SUM ([TOTAL]) as Total_Units,
   SUM ([OPEN]) as Open_Units
FROM [test].[dbo].[Tbl_Summary]
GROUP BY [Vc_MONTH],
     [Vc_PRODUCT]
```

Comment: Works perfect! This logic works for all the selects that I need. Thank Wil!

Comment: The UNION in the above answer should be a UNION ALL (: if not then what your doing is the distinct result of both table 1 and 2, and not table 1 + table 2

Comment: try GROUP BY GROUPING SETS then no union is required

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just use `grouping sets`.  Much simpler query and no `union`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN GROUPING([Vc_MONTH]) = 1 THEN 'ALL' ELSE [Vc_MONTH] END) as [Vc_MONTH],
       [Vc_STATE], [Vc_PRODUCT],
       SUM ([TOTAL]) as Total_Units,
       SUM ([OPEN]) as Open_Units
FROM [test].[dbo].[Tbl_Summary]
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (([Vc_MONTH], [Vc_REGION], [Vc_PRODUCT]),
                        ([Vc_REGION], [Vc_PRODUCT])
                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a SQL Server Guru by any stretch, but I think it has a `with` clause:

```
with monthly as (
  SELECT
    [Vc_MONTH], [Vc_STATE], [Vc_PRODUCT],
    SUM ([TOTAL]) as Total_Units,
    SUM ([OPEN]) as Open_Units
  FROM [test].[dbo].[Tbl_Summary]
  GROUP BY
    [Vc_MONTH], [Vc_STATE], [Vc_PRODUCT]
)
select
  [Vc_MONTH], [Vc_STATE], [Vc_PRODUCT],
  Total_Units, Open_Units
from monthly
union all
select
  '*ALL', [Vc_STATE], [Vc_PRODUCT],
  sum (Total_Units), sum (Open_Units)
from monthly
group by [Vc_STATE], [Vc_PRODUCT]
```